# Ejecutar aplicacion mvc .net framework 4.5.2 en ISS

Tags: .net, mvc, iis, windows-server

Amigos una consulta, resulta que hace unos meses estaba desarollando una aplicación en .net framework 4.5.2 con mvc; en su momento lo que llevaba para poder publicarlo sin problema y ejecutarlo en el IIS de windows server 2012 R2 me tocó compilarlo en .net framework 4.0 y no me generó errores.

Ahora resulta que le he hecho más modificaciones y necesito publicarlo, pero al momento de publicarlo solo me permite en .net framework 4.5.2 y si lo ejecuto en el servidor no me funciona.

Según lo que he investigado se debe a que el IIS esta intentando ejecutarlo en el .net framework 4.0 y al desarrollarse en una versión posterior, no permite

¿Alguno sabe que pueda hacer con esto para que me permita el servidor ejecutar la aplicación con el .net framework 4.5.2?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Instalar el .net framework 4.5.2 en el servidor

Comment: ya lo instale pero cuando ejecuto una aplicacion en el IIS me aparece como si estuviera ejecutando en 4.0

Comment: ¿Has reiniciado el IIS? ¿Has cambiado el .net framework en las propiedades de la aplicación?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya encontré el problema lo pude solucionar instalando la versión de framework 4.6.1 y luego reiniciando el servidor espero les sirva

Comment: Saludos que bueno encontraste la solución, por favor considera que cuando te sea posible marques tu respuesta como aceptada para indicar que es la solución al problema expuesto

Comment: framework 6.1???Solo hay hasta 4.8!!! (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history o https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies)

Comment: @iria estas en lo correcto me falto el 4 instale la version 4.6.1